window.webkit.messageHandlers is defined in an iOS Chrome & Firefox browser which is not in a Webview
I was under the assumption that webkit.messageHandlers are defined on iOS in a webview context. But when I do an alert of this, I get some kind of "value" that I cannot look into.
Can I get some clarity on this, and if someone has a more elegant way to check if a particular page is being displayed inside an iOS webview.
const isIOS = () => {
    alert(window.webkit?.messageHandlers)
    return window.webkit && window.webkit?.messageHandlers
}



Your assumption is generally correct—window.webkit.messageHandlers is used to communicate between JavaScript running in a webview and native iOS code. This interface allows JavaScript in a webview to send messages to the host app, which can respond or perform native actions
You can create a handler helper method for checking if the required handler is present are not


function isInsideIOSWebView(expectedHandler) {
    const handlers = window.webkit?.messageHandlers;

    if (!handlers) {
        return false; // No message handlers, so not in an iOS webview.
    }

    // Optionally, you can check for a specific handler to be more certain.

    if (handlers[expectedHandler]) {
        return true; // A known handler exists, indicating iOS webview.
    }

    // If you want to see what handlers are available, you can try logging them to console.
    console.log("Available message handlers:", handlers);

    return false; // No known handlers, unsure if in an iOS webview.
}

// Usage
if (isInsideIOSWebView()) {
    console.log("Inside an iOS webview");
} else {
    console.log("Not in an iOS webview");
}



